# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'day0_.calendar_id' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, wildfly

I already found multiple questions that were very similar to mine, but sadly none of the solutions helped me.

I need a many to one relation between the table Calendar and Day. A calendar can have multiple days.

here my code, thanks for looking at it:

Calendar class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="calendars")
@NamedQuery(name="Calendar.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Calendar c")

public class Calendar implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="calendar_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int calendarId;

private String background;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date begindate;
```

CalendarBean:

```
@EJB
CalendarEJB calendarEJB;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String calendarName;
private int calendarID;

public String getCalendarName() {
    return calendarName;
}

public void setCalendarName(String calendarName) {
    this.calendarName = calendarName;
}

public int getCalendarID() {
    return calendarID;
}

public void setCalendarID(int calendarID) {
    this.calendarID = calendarID;
}
```

Day class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="days")
@NamedQuery(name="Day.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Day d")
public class Day implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int iddays;

private int calendars_calendar_id;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Calendar
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="calendar_id")
private Calendar calendar;

public int getCalendars_calendar_id() {
    return calendars_calendar_id;
}

public void setCalendars_calendar_id(int calendars_calendar_id) {
    this.calendars_calendar_id = calendars_calendar_id;
}
```

DayBean:

```
@EJB
DayEJB dayEJB;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int iddays;
private int calendars_calendar_id;

private CalendarBean calendarb = new CalendarBean();

public int getIddays() {
    return iddays;
}

public void setIddays(int iddays) {
    this.iddays = iddays;
}

public int getCalendars_calendar_id() {
    return calendars_calendar_id;
}

public void setCalendars_calendar_id(int calendars_calendar_id) {
    this.calendars_calendar_id = calendars_calendar_id;
}

public List<Day> allDays(){
    return dayEJB.listAllDays();

}
```

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`calendars` (
`calendar_id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`calendarname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`background` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`begindate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`public` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`calendar_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `calender_id_UNIQUE` (`calendar_id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 121
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`days`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`days` (
`iddays` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`text` VARCHAR(450) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`link` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`calendars_calendar_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`iddays`),
INDEX `calendar_id_idx` (`calendars_calendar_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `calendar_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`calendars_calendar_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`calendars` (`calendar_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 8
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

i changed @JoinColumn(name="calendar_id") to the foreign key name but error stayed so i renamed the foreign key to this value also no change. If i rename the @JoinColumn(name="calendar_id") to calendars_calendar_id wildfly can not deploy at all.

console:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
... 133 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'day0_.calendar_id' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
... 149 more
```

here the wildfly console when renaming @joincolumn:

```
12:29:45,739 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS011411: Unexpected problem gathering statistics: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011477: Persistence unit 'Calendar-2dv012.war#Calendar-2dv012' is not available
at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.EntityManagerFactoryLookup.entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryLookup.java:44)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.management.HibernateEntityStatistics.getDynamicChildrenNames(HibernateEntityStatistics.java:145)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.DynamicManagementStatisticsResource.getChildren(DynamicManagementStatisticsResource.java:204)
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.AbstractModelResource$DelegateResource.getChildren(AbstractModelResource.java:254) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:252) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:239) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:225) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:254) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:239) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:225) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:254) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:239) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:225) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:254) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:239) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:225) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.Resource$Tools.readModel(Resource.java:213) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.writeModel(ModelControllerImpl.java:575) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.createPersistenceResource(OperationContextImpl.java:224) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:526) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:281) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.finishStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:698) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:673) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:484) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:281) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:276) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:271) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:145) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:555) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:551) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:551) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]

12:29:45,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "Calendar-2dv012.war" with deployment "Calendar-2dv012.war"
12:29:45,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."Calendar-2dv012.war#Calendar-2dv012": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Calendar-2dv012.war#Calendar-2dv012": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Calendar-2dv012] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

CalendarEjb:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CalendarEJB {

 @PersistenceContext (name = "CalendarEJB")
    EntityManager em;

 public List<Calendar> listAllCalendars(){

    TypedQuery<Calendar> theQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Calendar c", Calendar.class);
    List<Calendar> result = theQuery.getResultList();
    return result;  
 }

 public Calendar getCalendarById(int id){

        TypedQuery<Calendar> theQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Calendar c",           Calendar.class);
        List<Calendar> result = theQuery.getResultList();

        for(int i=0;i<=result.size()-1;i++){
            if(result.get(i).getCalendarId()== id){

                return result.get(i);
            }   
        }   
            return null;
     }
```

DayEjb:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DayEJB {

 @PersistenceContext (name = "DayEJB")
    EntityManager em;

 public List<Day> listAllDays(){

    TypedQuery<Day> theQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Day d", Day.class);
    List<Day> result = theQuery.getResultList();
    return result;  
 }

 public Day getDayById(int id){

        TypedQuery<Day> theQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Day d", Day.class);
        List<Day> result = theQuery.getResultList();

        for(int i=0;i<=result.size()-1;i++){
            if(result.get(i).getIddays()== id){

                return result.get(i);
            }   
        }   
            return null;
     }

 public void createDay(Day d){

     em.persist(d);
     System.out.println("Data Added Successfully"); 

 }
```

This is the Html:

```
<h:form>
                <h3>Days:</h3>
                <h:dataTable value="#{dayBean.allDays()}" var="day">

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                        #{day.iddays}
                        </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                        #{day.date}
                        </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Text</f:facet>
                        #{day.text}
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Link</f:facet>
                        #{day.link}
                        </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Calendar ID</f:facet>
                        #{day.calendars_calendar_id}
                        </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>

            </h:form>
```

Comment: Can you paste your DaoImpl where you execute your select?

Comment: You left too much for the readers to guess. None of the EJBs methods you are calling from the associated (managed) beans. Which line in which method causes the mentioned exception? Unrelated to the concrete problem : Why are creating a new instance of the `CalendarBean` using the `new` keyword here - `private CalendarBean calendarb = new CalendarBean();`? You should be getting its managed instance instead. Please consider following the Java naming conventions. Property names like `calendars_calendar_id` are not according to the general conventions.

Comment: thanks, i added the missing method and the calling html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your entity model does not match the database schema.

The entity model defines an association `Day -> Calendar` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "days")
public class Day implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="calendar_id")
    private Calendar calendar;
}
```

but in the database, the foreign key column is called `calendars_calendar_id`, not `calendar_id`.

Comment: I tried that earlier but wildfly could not start anymore afterwards. Just found out that (insertable = false, updatable = false) was missing then. Its working now. Thanks!